# How to manipulate spacing with SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am making a map of Brazil country with `SVG` and I have a doubt of `style`. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajaJVG) is the map snippet. I'd like to put a spacing between States like the example image below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Your snippet seems to exhibit the exact behavior you are looking for? Please clarify what your current code does not do and what you want it to do.

Comment: @AndrewFan 
My current code shows the Brazilian states only. You select which one you want and displays the respective name. Now I just want to change the style part.

Comment: Tricky. Usually, you could achieve this using a white `stroke` but this is not possible as you are using this property to do the [line drawing animation](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)... Is the animation strictly necessary?

Comment: @Xander No, it is not! How can I change?

Comment: @hunterxhunter check my answer, let me know if that's along the right lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the spacing between states, use `stroke-width`:

```
.mapa-svg-estados {
    stroke: var(--default-strok);
    stroke-width:3px;
}
```

To keep the animated line drawing, which also uses `stroke-width`, use `animation` rather than `transition`:

```
.mapa-svg-estados-active {
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke: var(--default-blue-stroke);
    stroke-dasharray: 180%;
    stroke-dashoffset: -120%;
    fill: var(--default-grey-black-fill);
    animation:outline 0.8s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes outline {
     from {}
     to {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
     }
}
```

I made a working fork from your CodePen [**here**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjVEVN).

*P.S. you have a typo `--default-strok` => `--default-stroke` ;)*